# How to remove the first character of a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

HI All,

In my js file i am getting an array of records (negetive values ) like this

```
deletedDetailIds = $.map(eformDetailIds, function(e) { return e < 0 ? e : null; });
```

For example the deletedDetailIds = -1234,-1235,-1256 like this.

Now i have to create an array and add these values with out negetive symbols. like

newArray = 1234,1235,1256.

Please help me in this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct way would be to use [**`Math.abs`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/abs):

```
$.map(eformDetailIds, function(e) { 
    return e < 0 ? Math.abs(e) : null; 
});
```

You could also multiply with `-1`.

You are dealing with numbers. Only the string representation contains a `-` to indicate the negative value, so you cannot really remove the first character here.

Answer (score 2):

Easy solution is multiply the values by -1 which make value + for you

example

```
var a = -12345 * -1;
   a = 12345;
```

Comment: While this is the correct solution, it is better to use Math.abs or at least have a conditional check so you don't accidentally negate a positive. Yes that wasn't part of the specifications, but you never know what crazy crap might happen.

Comment: well as per the OP he is getting - values ...thats y its require to multiply by -1 read question carefully

Comment: I know, I acknowledged that fact in "Yes that wasn't part of the specifications, but you never know what crazy crap might happen." Even if the question doesn't make the check seem necessary, it is still good practice.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
deletedDetailIds = $.map(eformDetailIds, function(e) { return e < 0 ? Math.abs(e) : null; });
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
deletedDetailIds = $.map(eformDetailIds, function(e) {
    return e < 0 ? Math.abs(e) : null;
})
```

Answer (score 1):

if u are willing for replace -ve symbol then,

```
deletedDetailIds.replace(/-/g, "");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use abs:

So
    Math.abs(number)

Where number will be the negative number

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
deletedDetailIds = $.map(eformDetailIds, function(e) { return e < 0 ? e : null; });
var total = 0;
$.each(deletedDetailIds, function(a, b){
 total += Math.abs(b)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    var deletedDetailIds = $.map(eformDetailIds, 
       function(item) { return item < 0 ? -item : null; }
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the Math.abs function:

```
$.map(eformDetailIds, function(e) { 
        return e && e < 0 ? Math.abs(e) : 0; 
});
```

More info [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_abs.asp)